# Why didn't Felix Baumgartner land very close to the launch site?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, projectile, atmospheric-science, drag

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Bull_Stratos#Launch):

> Baumgartner's ascent took approximately 2 1⁄2 hours, after which the capsule levelled at approximately 38 kilometres (24 mi). [...] The capsule returned to the ground via its own parachute, and landed approximately 70.5 kilometres (43.8 mi) east of Baumgartner's landing site.

If we abstract away the air friction from the parachute, why hasn't Baumgartner landed exactly near the same point where he took off?

I'm understanding this cannot be due to earth rotation since the atmosphere also rotates with the earth.

Edit: forgot to add detail about how much he "drifted" away.

Comment: "*If we abstract away the air friction from the parachute*" Then there'd be no point in a parachute...

Comment: @Steeven I doubt the parachute accounts for the 70km difference, which is why I chose to ignore it for this matter

Comment: "_why hasn't Baugmartner landed exactly near the same point where he took off?_" This assumes he took off vertically, then came down. Also, wind can push a parachutist quite a far distance from where he jumped, especially from such a high altitude.

Comment: @josephh But is 70km realistic to explain much of it, even from his altitude?

Comment: yes, it most definitely is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the text carefully, the 70.5 km is the distance between Baumgartner's landing site and the capsule's landing site. What we don't know is the time gap between Baumgartner's jump and the mission control command to the capsule which released the balloon and started the capsule's own descent. This is likely to be a significant time gap because you do not want your uncontrolled descending capsule to be anywhere near your descending skydiver or their recovery vehicles. So the distance between the two landing sites may well have been intentional.

The distance between the launch site and Baumgartner's landing site isn't given in the text you quoted, but using the latitude and longitude data in the Wikipedia article we can calculate this to be also approximately 70 km. But this is easily accounted for the the fact that the capsule took 2.5 hours to ascend. A drift of 70 km over 2.5 hours in a high altitude balloon requires an average wind speed of less than 30 km/hr, which is very possible.

Comment: @eckzu Yes. A balloon is unpowered and moves with the wind.

Comment: This is a satisfactory answer, thank you. Do we have historical data on the wind speed at the various altitudes in this region for the day Baumgartner accomplished his jump? I'll look into it.